# Let $G = ⟨a⟩$ be a cyclic group of order n. For each integer m, define a map $f_m :G−→G$ by $f_m(x)=x^m$ for every $x∈G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have done some parts of this question but other parts I am not sure...

> Let $G = ⟨a⟩$ be a cyclic group of order n. For each integer m, define a map $fm :G−→G$ by $f_m(x)=x^m$ for every $x∈G$
>
> (1) $f_m$ is a group homomorphism.
>
> (2) $f_m$ is an automorphism if and only if $gcd(m, n) = 1$
>
> (3) Find the kernel and image of $f_4$ when $n = 10$

The first part I believe is pretty simple.  $f_m(xy)=(xy)^m=x^my^m=f_m(x)f_m(y)$.

The next part we have to prove both directions.

For the backwards direction I think I am more clear with what I have to do.  We know from the first part $fm$ is a homomorphism.  So to prove it to be a automorphism we must show $fm$ is one to one and onto.  Let x and y exist in G and |G|=u.  Then $x^u=e=y^u$.  Since the gcd(m,n)=1 by defintion there exists a u and v in the integers s.t. $mu+nv=1$.  We can rearrange this and see $mu=1-nv$.

First we will show this is 1-1:

$x^m=y^m$

$x^{mu}=y^{mu}$

$x^{1-nv}=y^{1-nv}$

$x*x^{n(-v)}=y*y^{n(-v)}$

xe=ye

x=y

Now we will prove it is onto.  We need to pick a g that exists in G and find x that exists in G s.t. $fm(x)=x^m=y$. y=$y^1$=$y^{mu+nv}$=$y^{mu}y^{nv}=(y^{u})^m(y^{n})^v$.  I'm not sure what to do here after this...

The foward direction seems to be much harder.  We are assuming $fm$ is an isomorphism and proving the gcd(m,n)=2.  $fm$ is 1-1 and we can assume d=(m,n)>1.  I believe for this we can use the formula $ord(x)=n/gcd(m,n)=d>1$ but I am not sure how to get here.  For the beginning of the foward direction do we let x exist in G s.t $fm(x)=e$ or is that incorrect?

The third part I really have no idea.  I know the ker here is when $fm(x)=e$

Comment: Please, take a look at [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some math formatting guidance. In particular, _whole expressions_ can be enclosed in a single pair of dollar signs. Compare your `x^$(1-nv)$=y^$(1-nv)$` to a more conventional `$x^{1-nv}=y^{1-nv}$`: $x^{1-nv}=y^{1-nv}$. Also, note how to use underscores: `$f_m$` gives $f_m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

(2) *For the ontoness*, note that $x^n=e$ since your group has $n$ elements and you want to find an $x$ such that $x^m=y$.

Then
$$x=x^{mu+nv}=y^u$$

**Note** Since $f: G \to G$ is one-to-one and $G$ is finite, you can deduce directly that $f$ is onto, this is a well known set theory fact.

Show that this $y$ works.

*For the direct implication:* Assume by contradiction that $gcd(m,n)=d >1$. Write $m=dm',n=dn'$.

What is $f(a^{n'})$?

(3) $G=\{ e, a, a^2,..., a^9 \}$ and $a^{10}=e$.

By definition 
$$\ker(f_4)=\{ a^k : f_4(a^k)=e \}$$

This is equivalent to $a^{4k}=e$, which only happens if $10 |4k$.

Also
$$Im(f)=\{ f_4(a^k) : 0 \leq k \leq 9 \} = \{e, a^4, a^8,..., a^{36} \}$$

Use $a^{10}=e$ to write $Im(f)$ explicitely.

Comment: Okay the onto explanation makes sense.  For the contradiction I am still a little lost.  So I see what your saying with $n=dn'$ as I can rearrange it to be n'=n/d.  Is the goal now to plug it into $ord(x)=/(n/d,)=d$ when $x=a^{n/d}$ like I said before?  How would you go from there?  Also with the $Im(f)$ does this mean the the $Im(f)={20}$ since it's the only one where 10|20?  Thanks and sorry for late response

Comment: @user710744 Again, what is $f(a^{n'})$? As for the image, when you write explicitely $Im(f)$, you will see that half of them repeat.

Comment: $(^′)=(^{n/d})=(^{n/d})^m$ correct?  I don't see what your saying when half of them repeat... a^{10} is not even in the image I thought since we are going up by 4s.  Sorry for the confusion I just don't see it.

Comment: @user710744 $$(^{n/d})^m=(^{n/d})^{m' d}=??$$ As for the second part, what is $f_4(a^3)$?

Comment: So $(^{/})^{′}=a^{nm'}=a^n*a^{m/d}$.  So $a^n=e$ but what are we suppose to do with $a^{m/d}$.  For $_4(^3)=a^{12}$.  I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: @user710744 Your second inequality is not true: $a^{nm'}=(a^n)^{m'}$. Your RHS $a^n*a^{m'}$ is equal to $a^{n+m'}$.

Comment: My bad I knew that I don't know why I wrote that.  What does this prove though? lso for the other part if we look t $a^4=a^{16}$ etc. what is this showing none of them repeat

Comment: @user710744 It is showing that $f(a^{\frac{n}{d}})=f(e)$. As for the second question, what is $f_4(a^6)$? Again, write all 10 elements explicitely.

Comment: So this is a contradiction to our intital statement therefore $gcd(m,n)=1$.  The elements go as follows, ${e,a^4,a^8,a^{12},a^{16},a^{20},a^{24},a^{28},a^{32},a^{36}}$

Comment: @user710744 And what is $a^{12}$? What about $a^{16}$? Since $a^{10}=e$ you can bring all powers down between 0 and 9.

Comment: Oh okay so when you said half of them repeat your saying past 9 they begin repeating so for example $a^4=a^{44}$ correct?

Comment: @user710744 Exactly... Write explicitely what $a^{12},a^{16},a^{20},a^{24},a^{28},a^{32},a^{36}$ become and you will see your list.